# Summing values in Python list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum

I have this code where I am trying to append to a dictionary and after the loop terminates, print out the name and `saved_this_month` in dictionary format, plus print out the sum of the `saved_this_month`.  The latter part I am having issues with, in this case, the total_savings variable.  I think I am trying to pull the values for `index` in position 1 (the amounts) and sum them, but clearly, I am wrong.

Any ideas? Thanks.

```
savings_list = []

while True:
    bank = input('Enter the name of the bank:')
    savings_amount = float(input('Enter the amount saved:'))

    savings_list.append({
        "name": bank,
        "saved_this_month": savings_amount
        })
    total_savings = sum(savings_list[1]) **this is the prob line I think**

    cont = input('Want to add another? (Y/N)')
    if cont == 'N':
        break;

print(savings_list)
print(total_savings)
```

Comment: instead of `sum(savings_list[1])` it should be `sum(savings_list[bank])`

Comment: thanks @Stack.  I tried that and it gave me:  list indices must be integers or slices, not str.  i tried with savings_amount as well (im assuming you meant that) and got same error, except '.....not float'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is sum the savings amount entered, why not use a variable external to the `while` loop?

```
savings_list = []
total_savings = 0  # Define out here

while True:
    bank = input('Enter the name of the bank:')
    savings_amount = float(input('Enter the amount saved:'))

    savings_list.append({
        "name": bank,
        "saved_this_month": savings_amount
        })
    total_savings += savings_amount  # just a simple sum

    cont = input('Want to add another? (Y/N)')
    if cont == 'N':
        break;

print(savings_list)
print(total_savings)
```

If, however, you want to be fancy and calculate the sum after you have loaded the `savings_list`, you will need to convert the list of `dicts` into a list of something that `sum` knows how to handle.  Try a list comprehension (**EDIT**: or, even better, a [generator statement](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)):

```
total_savings = sum(x["saved_this_month"] for x in savings_list)
```

Unrolling the list comprehension:

```
a = []
for x in savings_list:
    a.append(x["saved_this_month"])
total_savings = sum(a)
```

Comment: thank you, that worked perfectly.  Thanks for the explanation as well

Comment: You don't need a list comprehension. A generator would be better. Just remove the outer square brackets in the sum. Nice answer.